# Django Admin - disable edit link for specific model instances

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-admin

I defined the following model:

```
class BankAccount(models.Model):
    iban = models.CharField(max_length=34)
    owner = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.SET_NULL, null=True, related_name='owner')
```

And the following ModelAdmin on admin.py:

```
class BankAccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('iban', 'owner',)

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj is None or obj.owner == request.user
```

So far, the django admin only allow Users to edit their bank account, returning a 403 Forbidden error when the user does not have change permission.

The problem is that the link is still displayed for all of BankAccount instances.

Any idea on how I could disable the link for those specific instances on the BankAccount admin view?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally implemented a workaround to solve it on admin.py as shown below. Comments explain the lines added.

```
from django.utils.html import format_html

class BankAccountAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('iban_link', 'owner',)
    list_display_links = None  # The field displaying the link is given by iban_link()

    editable_objs = []  # This variable will store the instances that the logged in user can edit

    def has_change_permission(self, request, obj=None):
        return obj is None or obj.owner == request.user

    def iban_link(self, obj):
        # Shows the link only if obj is editable by the user. 
        if obj in self.editable_objs:
            return format_html("<a href='{id}'>{iban}</a>",
                               id=obj.id, iban=obj.iban,
                               )
        else:
            return format_html("{iban}",
                               id=obj.id, iban=obj.iban,
                               )

    # We make use of get_queryset method to fetch request.user and store the editable instances
    def get_queryset(self, request):
        # Stores all the BankAccount instances that the logged in user is owner of
        self.editable_objs = BankAccount.objects.filter(owner=request.user)
        return super(UserAdmin, self).get_queryset(request)
```

Note that without the line `list_display_links = None` the links would still be displayed for all instances. This is because the default behaviour displays the links for all instances on the first column.